# Camunda BPM 7.2: show process variable in task-list (not form)

Tags: business-process-management, camunda

I installed camunda-bpm-wildfly-7.2.0, which comes with a deployed camunda-example-invoice-7.2.0.war.
In the task-list (i don't mean the task-form), process variables are displayed (e.g. Invoice Amount, Invoice Number etc.) for example for an Assign Approver task or an Approve Invoice task.

Now, when i deploy my own Process Application War, process variables (e.g. customerNumber, orderNumber) are displayed in the task form (embedded form), but not in the task-list! I marked the two variables readonly in the embedded task form and also in the user-task node in the modeller (properties, Form Fields).

What else do i have to do to display those variables in the task-list?

Thanks,
Michael

p.s.
unfortunately i can't post a screenshot; need at least 10 reputations...gargh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, figured out myself.

you have to edit the task-filters in the tasklist-app and add the process variables there.